# How to change dynamically inflated textview from after proceeding an action on other fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

So, what my problem is that in one fragment(w/i a viewpager, I'll call this Fragment A) I click on this dynamically created button that adds a new fragment(I'll call this Fragment B) in a framelayout which allows me to use PayPal service. On PayPal Activity result, Fragment B communicates with the main Activity via a communicator(an interface class) to call Fragment A to change that text. But I'm getting a null pointer exeception crash.

To be specific:

what I did was that I made a global TextView variable that is initialized on click. I did this b/c I have a list of other things that are dynamically inflated and to avoid the TextView from being initialized with wrong layout I initialized it on click.

```
bidChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                eventListChangeKey = keyVal;
                eventListChangeIdx = eventListIdx;
                eventBiddingChangeIdx = finalI;

                priceToChage = (TextView) biddersLayout.findViewById(R.id.single_list_bidder_bid_price);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("auctionID", auctionId);
                bundle.putInt("dateID", dateId);
                bundle.putInt("FromWhere", 2);

                Fragment fragment = new Fragment_Home_ItemInfo_Bid();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container_mainScreen, fragment, "itemInfo_bid")
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                        .commit();
            }
        });
```

In the main activity

```
public void changeBidderPrice(String s) {
    Fragment fragment = viewPagerAdapter.getItem(1);
    ((Fragment_List) fragment).changePrice(s);

}
```

is what I do

back in Fragment A

```
public void changePrice(String val) {
    priceToChage.setText(val);
    dataMap.get(eventListChangeKey).get(eventListChangeIdx).getBidList().get(eventBiddingChangeIdx).setPrice(val);

}
```

I've thought this over an over but I just can't figure this out. I've searched for similar cases in StackOverflow but I wasn't able to get a help.

Would the problem be the way I initialize that TextView? or is it the way I'm calling Fragment A from the main activity?

Comment: can you paste the stacktrace?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=131072, result=-1, data=Intent {  }} to activity {com.example.nictaehongkim.paytime_beta/com.example.nictaehongkim.paytime_beta.Activity_MainScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: I'm not sure if I called the wrong fragment causing this textview null or if the way I initialized it makes this textview null

Comment: It looks like it's more likely to be the second scenario. Try setting a message in the TextView right after this line `priceToChage = (TextView) biddersLayout.findViewById(R.id.single_list_bidder_bid_price);` and see if you get a NullPointerException

Comment: hmm I think it's the way I initialized that textView b/c when I removed priceToChange.setText(val) but left dataMap... line it works fine. if in any case would you know where and how to initialize that TextView?

Comment: Generally people create references to layout views right after inlating the layout in `onCreate`. I can't give a definite answer because there is a lot of unknowns. Does your layout file actually contain the textView? Is the TextView id really "single_list_bidder_bid_price"? Is the onClickListener actually called?

Comment: @Olumide I did as you've suggested and there is no apparent error occurrence. hmm... it sets the text just fine D: I'm getting more confused now

Comment: @Olumide There is this dynamically inflated LinearLayout and within that layout, there is a TextView with that id... 
your suggestions are actually giving me the right guidance Thanks :))

Comment: How many fragments do you have in the viewpager?

Comment: @Olumide I have four in total. I use pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2); in order to maintain fragments with index 0 and 1 from the viewpager.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, the paypal fragment is #4 and the textView is in fragment #1. If that's the case the setting the offscreen page limit to two won't help since, that'll only keep fragment #2, #3 and #4 in memory when the viewpager displays fragment #4, so increase it from 2 to 3

Comment: Um paypal integrated fragment is not in the viewpager

viewpager = [sth, Fragment A, sth, sth]
and when a button inside Fragment A is clicked a new Fragment B(paypal) is added.

Comment: So paypal becomes #5? If that's the case still increase the limit to 3

Answer (score 0):

for fragments `onViewCreated()` is called after onCreateView() and ensures that the fragment's root view is non-null. Any view setup should happen here. E.g., view lookups, attaching listeners.
source : [codepath](http://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments)

for activities `onCreate()`

Comment: yeah but once Fragment A is inflated within a viewpager and I'm calling that fragment by using adapter.getItem() aren't I fetching that fragment that's already in the memory? I haven't destroyed Fragment A at all. What i mean is that onCreateView is only called once. Isn't it?